# What is the order of the factor group Z/60Z /<15>?

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the order of the factor group Z/60Z/<15>?

I know how to do it when it's the order of the factor group Z60 /<15>, but these aren't the same so I feel lost. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why aren't they the same? (In the notation I'm used to, these are the same)

Comment: I had never seen it written this way before so I didn't think they were the same. But if they are the same then I understand the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can, for example, denote $\;\Bbb Z_{60}:=\Bbb Z/60\Bbb Z\;$ to avoid messy writing, so your question is what is the order of the quotient group $\;\Bbb Z_{60}/\langle 15\rangle\;$ , with $\;\langle15\rangle\;$ being the cyclic subgroup of $\;\Bbb Z_{60}\;$ generated by the element $\;15\pmod{60}\;$ ? You can see that then you can do it: it is just a matter of notation, nothing else.

$$1\cdot15=15\,,\,2\cdot15=30\,,\,3\cdot15=45\,,\,4\cdot15=60=0\pmod{60}\implies|\langle15\rangle|=4\implies$$

by Lagrange's Theorem we get

$$\left|\Bbb Z_{60}/\langle15\rangle\right|=\frac{|\Bbb Z_{60}|}{|\langle15\rangle|}=\frac{60}4=15$$

Comment: When you write it like that I understand they are the same notation. Thank you.